# Как на PHP скачать файлы с Minio?

Tags: php, minio

Есть файлы, выложенные на сервисе Minio, конкретно тут https://s3.inline-dmp.ru/minio/inbox/
есть Access key + token для доступа туда.
Как скачать оттуда файлы на php к себе на сервер?

Comment: curlом качайте файл

Answer (score 0):

В общем ничего в сети не нашел (по ссылке выше тоже), пришлось повторить все запросы через курл.